# How can I answer a command that needs input in Plink?

Tags: batch-file, plink

I run a command in Linux remote machine using plink (from batch file in Windows).

For example:

```
plink.exe -ssh root@IP -pw pass -m testCommands.txt >> uninstall.log
```

In `testCommands.txt` I have a command that perform uninstall of application, 
the problem is that command of "uninstall" require an answer (`y` or `n`),
How can I send answer in addition to what I already send?

Here is the question I have:

> [?7hAre you sure you want to completely remove "APPLICATION" and all of its components?
>   Yes [y, Enter], No [n]"

Answer (score 1):

There are several options...

- Use a `-y` or auto-confirm option on the command that removes the software, e.g.

  ```
  pkg rm -yes somePackacge
  ```
- Use a pipe to send the `yes`, so that the command you run in PLINK looks like

  ```
  printf "Yes\n" | pkg rm some_package
  ```

  or

  ```
  yes | pkg rm some_package
  ```
- Make the command that you run on the Linux machine be based on `expect` which can `spawn` your remove command, `wait` for a question and then `send` it a confirmation. Some `expect` examples [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/).